# При изменении файла CSS, на сайте ничего не меняется (КЭШ чистил) сайт на хостинге

Tags: css, wordpress, сервер, хостинг

Загрузил сайт на хостинг, все сразу было хорошо, после перестало меняться в CSS. HTML и JS меняются. Файл подключен правильно, ибо до этого работало, а так же после изменении файла CSS, я захожу на сервер и там вижу эти изменения, но вот на самом сайте ничего не меняется.
Кэш чистил :

1. В доп настройках хрома
2. CTRL + F5
3. плагины вордпресс
4. F12 --> Network --> Disable cache
5. Открывал в инкогнито
6. открывал в других браузерах
7. в css файлах добавлял версию css?2423 или css?v=423423
   перепробовал уже много чего, но ничего не помогает

Comment: А сам файл css в браузере посмотреть?

Comment: Смотрел, ничего не появляется, но на сервере все изменения сразу же появляются

Comment: Либо сервер не тот, либо ещё какой кеш, например, Cloudflare

Comment: Возможно я нашел причину. Обратился в тех. поддержку сервера и там ответили " может быть связана с включенным кешированием для сайтов на стороне защиты от DDoS-атак, которая у вас подключена."